# How does mysql lock my data when using secondary index?

Tags: mysql

I use these data;

> CREATE TABLE `t` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, `c` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `d` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `c` (`c`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;insert into t values(0,0,0),(5,5,5),(10,10,10),(15,15,15),(20,20,20),(25,25,25);

and I execute sql in the following order;
[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2RsD.png)

Why sessionB is blocked, but sessionC is not

Comment: I don't know how to use tables on stack overflow markdown, only pictures

Comment: look at `show engine innodb status`

Comment: I got the engine inoodb status and put it below

Comment: I know the reason, gaplock only prevents inserts, not updates